# Split line by nearest points using geopandas

Tags: shapely, splitting, snapping, geopandas

I have two GeoPandas Dataframes. 
One is a combination of linestrings, when plotted is a single line. The other GeoDataFrame contains rows where each row is a unique point close to to the first line.

Now I would like to split the line using the locations of the points returning a GeoDataFrame.

Where my input looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First make sure you union your GeoDataFrames into a MultiLineString and MultiPoint

```
line = gdf_line.geometry.unary_union
coords = gdf_point.geometry.unary_union
```

Using `shapely.ops.snap` and `shapely.ops.split` it is possible to `snap` the points to the line (with a given `tolerance`) and use this to `split` the `line`. Result is a GeometryCollection

```
split(line, snap(coords, line, tolerance=1)
```

To combine this and return a GeoDataFrame use the following function:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import split, snap


def split_line_by_nearest_points(gdf_line, gdf_points, tolerance):
    """
    Split the union of lines with the union of points resulting 
    Parameters
    ----------
    gdf_line : geoDataFrame
        geodataframe with multiple rows of connecting line segments
    gdf_points : geoDataFrame
        geodataframe with multiple rows of single points
        
    Returns
    -------
    gdf_segments : geoDataFrame
        geodataframe of segments
    """
    
    # union all geometries
    line = gdf_line.geometry.unary_union
    coords = gdf_points.geometry.unary_union

    # snap and split coords on line
    # returns GeometryCollection
    split_line = split(line, snap(coords, line, tolerance))

    # transform Geometry Collection to GeoDataFrame
    segments = [feature for feature in split_line.geoms]

    gdf_segments = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        list(range(len(segments))), geometry=segments)
    gdf_segments.columns = ['index', 'geometry']

    return gdf_segments
```

Which can be plotted as follows (where I find the `tolerance` variable still trial and error):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
gdf_line.plot(ax=ax, lw=6, color='gray')
gdf_segments.plot(ax=ax, column='index', lw=3, cmap='Paired')
gdf_points.plot(ax=ax, zorder=3)
```

[image]

**--EDIT**

the `snap` function is not similar as a `nearest_point` query. I end up using the function https://github.com/ojdo/python-tools/blob/master/shapelytools.py#L144 from https://github.com/ojdo/python-tools that provides many interesting functions for shapely

Comment: You can accept your own answer with the checkbox