# Merging line layers and then splitting the result at a point layer using Python script

Tags: python, postgis, software-recommendations

I am very new to Python and I need to write a function which filters two line feature classes by type, then merges the results, then splits the merged-lines at a filtered-by-type point feature class. all the data is stored in postgre database.

Are there libraries having these functionalities I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoPandas should do the trick for most vector-based manipulation. It has a lot of dependencies though, so you may want to create a new conda environment for it like so:

```
conda create -n <environment name> geopandas other-packages-you-want
```

So, first load you data in a GeoDataFrame (GDF) from your database. I have no experience with that, but I hope this should help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732075/geopandas-postgis-connection

Then, suppose you have a GDF like so:
id type        geometry
0   car-roads  LINESTRING (4017476.264886954 19792128.2156728)
1   path       LINESTRING (4030453.382825969 19837548.1284593)

Then, you 'filter two line feature classes by type' I'm assuming you just want to select a specific value for a certain attribute? Since they are already line features? So, for the GeoDataFrame LFClass, with desired value for an attribute, you would query like this:

```
line1 = line1.loc[line1['type']=='car-roads']
```

Now line1 contains only lines for which the 'attribute' column is 12:

```
id type      geometry
0  car-roads LINESTRING (4030453.382825969 19837548.1284593)
```

Then, perform your merge operation using any of the functions  in the [documentation](https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html) I think you'll want the .append function, to just add the two classes together:

```
line1.append(line2)
```

For the final step, I found [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268518/split-line-by-nearest-points-using-geopandas), that describes exactly what you need (code copied:)

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import split, snap


def split_line_by_nearest_points(gdf_line, gdf_points, tolerance):
    """
    Split the union of lines with the union of points resulting 
    Parameters
    ----------
    gdf_line : geoDataFrame
        geodataframe with multiple rows of connecting line segments
    gdf_points : geoDataFrame
        geodataframe with multiple rows of single points

    Returns
    -------
    gdf_segments : geoDataFrame
        geodataframe of segments
    """

    # union all geometries
    line = gdf_line.geometry.unary_union
    coords = gdf_points.geometry.unary_union

    # snap and split coords on line
    # returns GeometryCollection
    split_line = split(line, snap(coords, line, tolerance))

    # transform Geometry Collection to GeoDataFrame
    segments = [feature for feature in split_line]

    gdf_segments = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        list(range(len(segments))), geometry=segments)
    gdf_segments.columns = ['index', 'geometry']

    return gdf_segments
split_line_by_nearest_points(line1,busstations,tolerance)
```

hope it works!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. just to clarify the problem: I have 2 line layers with different sets of attribute. I want to first filter "line1" based on its type for instance I only want the "car-roads". then I want to merge the resulting geometries to "line2" layer which already contains linear geometries of the same type. now I have one line layer which has the results I want. Then I want to split these lines "at" points which are simply bus station locations. so the final result should be lines connecting these bus stations together like a graph. I hope it's more clear now

Comment: @ngr aln: I edited my answer

Comment: thank you so so much. that's what I needed!

Comment: then, you can accept this answer, so people will know it is answered