# Create MultiLineStrings segments between points with Python Shapely

Tags: python, point, shapely, linestring

I have a layer of LineString and MultiLineString geometries. I'm trying to create a single geometry of the LineStrings split by certain snapped points.

This is an illustration of the current data that I have.
[image]

I would like to create a single MultiLineString element that merges all the LineStrings between the green points. An example of a single MultiLineString (yellow line) would look like,

[image]

I'm using the following Python code to try to do this.

```
import geopandas as gpd

import shapely
from shapely import geometry, ops
from shapely.ops import split, snap
from shapely.geometry import Point

def split_line_by_nearest_points(line, gdf_points, tol=5):
    coords = gdf_points.geometry.unary_union
    split_line = split(line, coords)
    segments = [feature for feature in split_line]
    gdf_segments = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        list(range(len(segments))), geometry=segments)
    gdf_segments.columns = ['index', 'geometry']

    return gdf_segments


merged_line = ops.linemerge(df_prim['geometry'].unary_union)
df_prim_split = split_line_by_nearest_points(merged_line, df_prot, tol=15)
```

The split line function is based on this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268518/split-line-by-nearest-points-using-geopandas)

Where df_prim is a geopandas dataframe of LineStrings and df_prot is a geopandas dataframe of points.

However, when I use the code described above, the geometry segments are created between each point and each vertex. The segments from this code look something like. Where the red line indicates an example segment which is split at verticies.

[image]